# get/set android widget image view size programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a widget. and an image view in that; I want to get/set size of the ImageView programmatically; And do this for other view like relativeLayout and ..... How Can I do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
**get the width and height of an android.widget.ImageView**

    int finalHeight, finalWidth;
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size_label);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
            finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
            tv.setText("Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
            return true;
        }
    });
// if not declare in xml layout
myImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

**Set ImageView width and height programmatically**

image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
```

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
myImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Comment: how can I find imageview on widget ?